# Matching hostname on string when it has no protocol://?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, pattern-matching

I use this js code to match a hostname from a string:

```
url.match(/:\/\/(www\.)?(.[^/:]+)/);
```

This works when the url has protocol:// at the beginning. For example:

This works fine:

```
var url = "http://domain.com/page";
url.match(/:\/\/(www\.)?(.[^/:]+)/);
```

But this doesn't:

```
var url = "domain.com/page";
url.match(/:\/\/(www\.)?(.[^/:]+)/);
```

I have tried:

```
url.match(/(:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.[^/:]+)/);
```

And that matches fine the hostname when it doesn't contain protocol://, but when it does contains it it only returns the protocol and not the hostname.

**How could I match the domain when it doesn't contains it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK before you have a brain meltdown from @xanatos answer here is a simple regex for basic needs. The other answers are more complete and handle more cases than this regex :

```
(?:(?:(?:\bhttps?|ftp)://)|^)([-A-Z0-9.]+)/
```

Group 1 will have your host name. URL parsing is a fragile thing to do with regexes. You were on the right track. You had two regexes that worked partially. I simply combined them.

Edit : I was tired yesterday night. Here is the regex for jscript

```
if (subject.match(/(?:(?:(?:\bhttps?|ftp):\/\/)|^)([\-a-z0-9.]+)\//i)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: +1 Small notes: you should tell him to activate ignore case, escape the `/` at the end, perhaps add support for [IPv6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740593(v=vs.85).aspx) addresses (ok... I'm exxagerating here).... and I normally would try to be coherent. If you use lowercase somewhere you always use lowercase. Ah and you took him away the "option" of :port (his one accepted it)... And both your and his don't support `http://username:password@site`

Answer (score 4):

I used [this function](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) from Steven Levithan, it parses urls quite decently.

Here's how you use this function

```
  alert(parseUri("www.domain.com/foo").host)
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @FailedDev I would say this is a terse not-high quality answer. But it's a possible solution to the problem of the OP.

Comment: @xanatos I did not say it is not a solution. But simple links could simply go to the comments? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @FailedDev: I have expanded the answer with a code example, please take a look.

Comment: @thg435 I have nothing against you. But I too have gotten the same "treatment" when I posted an external link as an answer to a question. I reverted my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
var rx = /^(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?:(?:(?:\/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|\/)+|\?|#)?(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?$/;
```

should be the uber-url parsing regex :-) Taken from here http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qznzx/1/

It shows the uselessness of regexes.

Comment: Haha. +1 just for "uselessness of regexes" :D

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit more complex than necessary but it seems to work:

```
^((?:.+?:\/\/)?(?:.[^/:]+)+)$
```

1. A non-capturing group for the protocol. From the start of the string
   match any number of characters until a `:`. There may be zero or one
   protocol.
2. A non-capturing group for the rest of the url. This part must exist.
3. Group it all up in single group.

Comment: I would have written `^(?:[^:]+:\/\/)?([^\/:]+)` to get the hostname.